# Ensuring the same output for a given input (pure function)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, functional-programming, dynamics-crm-2011

In my conquest to try to program in a more functional way, I have come up with the following static function:

```
public static class BaseService
{
    public static T EntityGet<T>(Guid id, XrmServiceContext xrmServiceContext) where T : Entity
    {
        return xrmServiceContext.CreateQuery<T>().Single(query => query.Id == id);
    }
}
```

**How can we ensure that it is deterministic and always returns the same value for a specified input?**

Please note that **XrmServiceContext** is a repository, and may throw depending on whether the connection is up or down.

Should we perhaps wrap the return type into a **[Maybe](https://github.com/AndreyTsvetkov/Functional.Maybe)**? :

```
public static Maybe<T> EntityGet<T>(Guid id, XrmServiceContext xrmServiceContext) where T : Entity
{
    return xrmServiceContext.CreateQuery<T>().Single(query => query.Id == id).ToMaybe();
}
```

This way we can be 100% sure of the return value.

**Question:**
After the *Maybe* change, can we now have completely deterministic behavior, regardless of whether the repository is up or down?

Comment: Single will throw an exception if database is down, so execution will not reach ToMaybe. Also I'm not sure how any function which calls the database (external storage) can be pure in a strict sense.

Comment: i dont know. can we conclude that you cannot have a pure function ever that makes a database call?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your call a try catch, and in the finally, always return a maybe, but I'm not sure this is a course of action I would recommend. This means every single call site that is retrieving the entity would have to handle checking the maybe, and then deciding what to do if it fails.

In this case, rather than a pursuit of "perfection"
[image]
I'd accept that errors happen, and they will bubble up.  Also, since you're dealing with a database, there is no guarantee that the value is going to exist in the database, or it will be the same value (un-updated).

Answer (score 1):

This code, `xrmServiceContext.CreateQuery<T>().Single(query => query.Id == id).ToMaybe();`, is problematic because `IQueryable.Single` will throw an `InvalidOperationException` if nothing matches the query.

You need to use the `IQueryable.SingleOrDefault` here to avoid the exception and return a null value (assuming you want a null.) You still need to wrap it in a Try/Catch to handle issues such as database outage, timeouts, etc. Setting up the Try is inexpensive but the Catch can be expensive so we want to avoid using it for logic. By using the `SingleOrDefault` you handle the most common exception, because the Id doesn't exist, and allow the Catch to only handle the unexpected (network failure, etc.)

```
public static T EntityGet<T>(Guid id, OrganizationServiceContext xrmServiceContext) where T : Entity
{           
    try
    {
        return xrmServiceContext.CreateQuery<T>().SingleOrDefault(query => query.Id == id);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Log the exception or this could create a debugging nightmare down the road!!!
        return default(T);
    }            
}
```

If you want to write that using the `Functional.Maybe` library you can:

```
public static Maybe<T> EntityGet<T>(Guid id, OrganizationServiceContext xrmServiceContext) where T : Entity
{
    try
    {
        return xrmServiceContext.CreateQuery<T>().SingleOrDefault(query => query.Id == id).ToMaybe();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Log the exception or this could create a debugging nightmare down the road!!!
        return Maybe<T>.Nothing;
    }
}
```